# New monitor white screen on boot

Tags: display, white-screen

I recently upgraded my monitors and upon booting into Ubuntu 20.04  I get a white screen with lines of green/purple pixels (see picture). Currently using displayport for both screens, I tried a brand new cord, as well as hdmi. The new displayport cord had the same result, hdmi doesn't produce any visual.

[image: Reference]

The monitors work fine when booting into Windows which leads me to believe it's an issue with linux.

- Monitors are XL2411P by Zowie
- Display Adapter: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 Super
- Processor: i5-9600K @ 3.7
- Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB with Linux Installed
- Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB with Windows Installed

Any advice helps.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a driver issue (surprise)

I ran

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

then rebooted and it seemed to fix the issue.

Hope this helps someone in the future!